# Using default route parameters for non-required Kohana Route::url

Tags: kohana, kohana-routing

I have a route setup that looks like this:

```
Route::set('my_route', 'r/<controller>(/<action>)(/(<name>-)<hash>)', array(
    'controller'    => '[a-z]+',
    'action'        => '[a-z]+',
    'hash'          => '\w{13}',
    'name'          => '[a-z]+',
))->defaults(array(
    'directory'     => 'my_dir',
    'controller'    => 'welcome',
    'action'        => 'index',
    'name'          => null,
));
```

Which works by itself. The problem comes in when I try and build a URL from the route, like this:

```
return Route::url('my_route', array(
    'action'    => 'test',
));
```

I get this error message:

```
Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: Required route parameter not passed: name
```

So if I set name to `null`, I get the same result.
If I set name to `false`, there is no error message, but the urls look like this:

`/r/welcome/test/-`

notice the - on the end?
Now I could strip that off, but I'm hoping there’s a better way.

---

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are trying to fix your routing by using 1 route for all. This is not the right way to do things.

Just make multiple routes (maybe you have to tweak this):

```
Route::set('my_route', 'r/<controller>(/<action>)/(<name>-)<hash>', array(
    'controller'    => '[a-z]+',
    'action'        => '[a-z]+',
    'hash'          => '\w{13}',
    'name'          => '[a-z]+',
))->defaults(array(
    'directory'     => 'my_dir',
    'controller'    => 'welcome',
    'action'        => 'index',
    'name'          => null,
));

Route::set('my_route2', 'r/<controller>(/<action>)', array(
    'controller'    => '[a-z]+',
    'action'        => '[a-z]+',
    'hash'          => '\w{13}',
    'name'          => '[a-z]+',
))->defaults(array(
    'directory'     => 'my_dir',
    'controller'    => 'welcome',
    'action'        => 'index',
    'name'          => null,
));
```

Remember the route system is really powerful and more routes doesn't mean it gets slower. So just make as many clearly possible routes and don't try to run everything by 1 route.